# import QuantLib as ql ERROR

Tags: python, linux, quantlib

I downloaded and installed `pyql` using `python setup.py install`

If I import things I need one by one from `pyql`, it works, e.g.,

```
from quantlib.instruments.api import AmericanExercise,EuropeanExercise, EuropeanOption, \
     VanillaOption, Put, Call
from quantlib.instruments.payoffs import PlainVanillaPayoff
```

However, if I try

```
import QuantLib as ql


[idf@mail python]$ python bootstrap_yc.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bootstrap_yc.py", line 1, in <module>
    import QuantLib as ql
ImportError: No module named QuantLib
[idf@mail python]$
```

I added the directory of the `quantlib` egg file in anaconda to `PYTHONPATH` to no avail.

```
[idf@mail python]$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/home/idf/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/quantlib-0.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/quantlib
[idf@mail python]$
```

**EDIT**

I am able to say

```
from quantlib import *

import quantlib as ql
```

But then things like

```
# Deposit rates
depo_maturities = [ql.Period(6,ql.Months), ql.Period(12, ql.Months)]
depo_rates = [5.25, 5.5]
```

return an error:

```
[idf@mail python]$ python bootstrap_yc.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bootstrap_yc.py", line 18, in <module>
    depo_maturities = [ql.Period(6,ql.Months), ql.Period(12, ql.Months)]
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Period'
[idf@mail python]$
```

Comment: May you post an example of what works when you import a single thing?

Comment: I mean when I say, from quantlib.instruments.api import AmericanExercise,EuropeanExercise, EuropeanOption, \
     VanillaOption, Put, Call
from quantlib.instruments.payoffs import PlainVanillaPayoff etc...See edit to original post.

Comment: See the EDIT portion as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're confusing pyql with the Python bindings provided by the QuantLib project.  pyql is a separate project, and gives you a `quantlib` module with a more idiomatic interface but with fewer features at this time.

If you want the QuantLib Python bindings, you can get them from the [QuantLib download page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/quantlib/files/QuantLib/) (look in the "other languages" folder inside any of the listed versions); installation instructions are at http://quantlib.org/install.shtml.

Comment: Oops, I did get confused. You might want to add a "requirements" section in your examples pointing to this library. It is easy to get confused. I am having  a problem with python-swig but will do explain that on another thread.

Comment: Yes, it might be an idea. Where did you get the example from?

Comment: There are several places. I forget exactly where, but here is one of the ones I tried to get to work http://gouthamanbalaraman.com/blog/short-interest-rate-model-calibration-quantlib.html

Comment: Actually it was this one http://gouthamanbalaraman.com/blog/quantlib-term-structure-bootstrap-yield-curve.html